# Request DTO with private setters

Tags: servicestack

I have a DTO like so:

```
public class UserPreferenceDto
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
    // other props with getter and setter

    //props WITHOUT setter, they are set in the ctor
    public string UserName { get; }
    public string ComputerName { get; }
    public string ApplicationCode { get; }
    public string ApplicationVersion { get; }
    public string PreferenceGroup { get; }

    public UserPreferenceDto(string userName, string computerName, string applicationCode, string applicationVersion, string preferenceGroup)
    {
        // Initializers of other props

        UserName = userName.ToLower();
        ComputerName = computerName.ToLower();
        ApplicationCode = applicationCode.ToLower();
        ApplicationVersion = applicationVersion.ToLower();
        PreferenceGroup = preferenceGroup.ToLower();
    }

    public string GetUrnKey()
    {
        return $"pref:{UserName}:{ComputerName}:{ApplicationCode}:{ApplicationVersion}:{PreferenceGroup}:{Id}";
    }
}
```

On the client (WPF app in C#) id have:

```
private void ChangeApplicationTheme()
{
    Debug.WriteLine($"Changeing application theme to {SelectedTheme}...");
    CurrentApp.SetApplicationTheme(SelectedTheme);
    var themePrefDto = new UserPreferenceDto(CurrentApp.GetCurrentUserLogonId(), System.Environment.MachineName, "AccountManagerClient", "1.0.000", "Theme");
    themePrefDto.CUser = CurrentApp.GetCurrentUserLogonId();
    themePrefDto.Preferences.Add("Theme", SelectedTheme);
    StorePreferenceItem(themePrefDto);
}

private async void StorePreferenceItem(UserPreferenceDto preferenceItem)
{
    #region Update server
    IsOperationRunning = true;
    OperationProgressText = $"Updating preferences item {preferenceItem}";
    try
    {
        var ssc = CurrentApp.ServiceClient;
        var pref = new CreateUserPreference(preferenceItem);
        await ssc.PostAsync(pref);
        //...
    }
    catch (WebServiceException we)
    {
        // ....
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // ...
    }
    finally
    {
        IsOperationRunning = false;
        OperationProgressText = string.Empty;
    }

    #endregion

    // .... 
}
```

On the serverside all props which **do NOT have a setter** are NULL. Looks like the **constructor is ignored**. *Is this by design?*

Since these props form a key in Redis, I need to make sure they have a value. Is it correct, that I have do declare public setters in my DTO and then *use Validators to make sure all props are set*??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes DTOs (Data Transfer Objects) by design are meant to have serializable properties with public getters/setters and a parameterless constructor.